# How to get the details of the current Netflix video you're watching?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, netflix

I'm trying to make a Chrome Extension for Netflix, and I'm curious if there's away to get details about the current video being played. I just want to extract the title of the video. I've seen that the Netflix API has been shut down so I'm curious if this is even possible?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
document.getElementsByClassName('player-status-main-title')
```

or with out the html

```
document.getElementsByClassName('player-status-main-title')[0].innerHTML
```

Comment: Oh thank you! I couldn't inspect the page while the videoplayer was there for some reason. This is exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: Ah I see, Thanks for the tip!

Comment: If the answer works for you go ahead and mark the answer correct, in case someone else needs it.

Comment: Marked! Sorry been viewing Stackoverflow for years, but I'm still a newbie when it comes to actually asking questions.